# Checking value of a related model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have users. Users have a relationship with a country, and country has a region.

I would like to access all users who are within a region, and I am doing it through their related country, like this:

user->country->region

When I tried to use whereHas, like this:

```
 $users = User::whereHas('country', function ($query) {
            $query->where('region', 3);
        })
        ->get();
```

I got an error that said there was an unexpected } on the 3rd line. I would like to know what is the best method of doing this.

Comment: The exception is probably not your posted code. Please post **all** the code related to your question. Your code should get you what you want

Comment: This is not really a laravel nor eloquent error, it's PHP syntax error. Check your code for proper closing brackets, braces... or missing semicolons ";" might be the issue.... I'd strongly recommend you to use IDE or some kind of PHPLint to avoid these errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Laravel Eloquent relationship, In Laravel eloqunent there are Has Many Through option available for as per your requirement.
Please check this :-> [Here is laravel documentation link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)